# How to bundle install a local path gem with docker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rubygems

I am using docker and rails.

I created a local gem and put it into vendor/gems folder.

And I add this into my Gemfile:

```
gem 'my_gem', path: './vendor/gems/my_gem'
```

In my Dockerfile

```
RUN mkdir /testapp
WORKDIR /testapp
ADD Gemfile /testapp/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /testapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /testapp
```

After run `docker-compose build`, it shows:

```
The path `/testapp/vendor/gems/my_gem` does not exist.
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 13
```

Comment: If the path does not exist, why don't you make it? RUN mkdir -p /testapp/vendor/gems/my_gem

Answer (score 13):

After I add this in Dockerfile, it worked.

```
ADD vendor/gems/my_gem /testapp/vendor/gems/my_gem
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add following at your Dockerfile:

```
RUN gem install --local path_to_gem/filename.gem
```